# Add slow external project to cmake

Tags: cmake, build, external-project

I am using an external dependency that is shipped as a tar archive inside the source tree. I am building the autotools project by using

```
ExternalProject_Add
```

This project will almost never change but takes multiple minutes to compile (way longer than the rest of the source code). After each

```
make clean
```

The install directory of the external project is still there but it gets extracted and rebuilt during the next compilation. Is there a way to keep this external project while cleaning / only build it once if the archive does not change?

Comment: How do you extract the archive in the `ExternalProject_Add` call?

Comment: I specify the archive as URL so it is extracted during the "download" step